# Add admin pagination with custom array of data?

Tags: magento2

I have an array with the structure like:

```
$list = array(
    '0' => array(
        'name' => 'First',
        'version' => '1',
    ),
    '1' => array(
        'name' => 'second',
        'version' => '2',
    ),
    '2' => array(
        'name' => 'third',
        'version' => '3',
    ),
    '3' => array(
        'name' => 'fourth',
        'version' => '4',
    ),
    ...So on...
```

I am showing this array data in custom html table using phtml file. Now, i want to add pagination and a search box with this table. What is the best way to do so in Magento 2.

Please Help..!!

Comment: where you want to show ? in admin or on frontend ?

Comment: In admin, i have created a custom page and page having table working fine. But now i want to add pagination on the table and a search box.

Answer (score 0):

for that consider the following example from devdocs:
To enable pagination for the listing component, the pagination component is declared as a child of the listing component in component instance configuration.

Example:

/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_page_listing.xml

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <container name="page_listing_top">
        <paging name="listing_paging">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">cms_block_listing.cms_block_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.paging</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">cms_block_listing.cms_block_listing.cms_block_columns.ids</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </paging>
    </container>
</listing>
```

Comment: can you please explain how this will apply for custom array data?

Comment: same as you have used Magento_ui on specific table. Not custom array of data. its proper mechanism to render grid from table. If you are doing some thing custom then its not related to Magento you have to use you some custom logic and this logic is not related to M2